# How to check if an Array contains specific term - Android

Tags: android, arrays, list, search, contains

I currently have a statement which reads

```
if(Arrays.asList(results).contains("Word"));
```

and I want to add at least several more terms to the .contains parameter however I am under the impression that it is bad programming practice to have a large number of terms on one line..

My question is, is there a more suitable way to store all the values I want to have in the .contains parameters?

Thanks

Comment: To answer the bigger question, could you tell us. Why you have a list of words and why you want to check for 4-5 different ones?

Comment: What do you mean more terms to the parameter? Like, you'd be searching for an entire sentence or what?

Comment: @jpom he means `if(Arrays.asList(results).contains("Word") || Arrays.asList(results).contains("Word2") || Arrays.asList(results).contains("Word3"))`

Comment: Say I have a list of football players, and I would like to do, if(Arrays.asList(players).contains("tom","selleck","bill"));

I am also only after realising that you cannot put an OR operator in the .contains() ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use intersection of two lists:

```
String[] terms = {"Word", "Foo", "Bar"};
List<String> resultList = Arrays.asList(results);
resultList.retainAll(Arrays.asList(terms))
if(resultList.size() > 0)
{
         /// Do something
}
```

To improve performance though, it's better to use the intersection of two `HashSet`s:

```
String[] terms = {"Word", "Foo", "Bar"};
Set<String> termSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(terms));
Set<String> resultsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(results));
resultsSet.retainAll(termSet);
if(resultsSet.size() > 0)
{
         /// Do something
}
```

As a side note, the above code checks whether *ANY* of the terms appear in `results`. To check that *ALL* the terms appear in results, you simply make sure the intersection is the same size as your term list:

```
 resultsSet.retainAll(termSet);
 if(resultSet.size() == termSet.size())
```

Comment: I am trying this method now however I am getting a "Cannot invoke size() on the primitive type boolean" error

Comment: Oops. You are right. The method `retainAll` changes the original collection and returns a boolean. I edited the answer to fix this.

Comment: It's really not necessary to create a temporary Set object.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Android's `java.util.Collections`
 class to help you with this.  In particular, `disjoint` will be useful:

> Returns whether the specified collections have no elements in common.

Here's a code sample that should get you started.

In your Activity or wherever you are checking to see if your results contain a word that you are looking for:

```
    String[] results = {"dog", "cat"};
    String[] wordsWeAreLookingFor = {"foo", "dog"};
    boolean foundWordInResults = this.checkIfArrayContainsAnyStringsInAnotherArray(results, wordsWeAreLookingFor);
    Log.d("MyActivity", "foundWordInResults:" + foundWordInResults);
```

Also in your the same class, or perhaps a utility class:

```
private boolean checkIfArrayContainsAnyStringsInAnotherArray(String[] results, String[] wordsWeAreLookingFor) {
    List<String> resultsList = Arrays.asList(results);
    List<String> wordsWeAreLookingForList = Arrays.asList(wordsWeAreLookingFor);
    return !Collections.disjoint(resultsList, wordsWeAreLookingForList);
}
```

Note that this particular code sample will have contain true in `foundWordInResults` since "dog" is in both `results` and `wordsWeAreLookingFor`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store your `results` in a `HashSet`? With a HashSet, you can benefit from hashing of the keys, and it will make your assertion much faster.

`Arrays.asList(results).contains("Word")` creates a temporary List object each time just to do linear search, it is not efficient use of memory and it's slow.

There's `HashSet.containsAll(Collection collection)` method you can use to do what you want, but again, it's not efficient use of memory if you want to create a temporary List of the parameters just to do an assertion.

I suggest the following:

```
HashSet hashSet = ....
public assertSomething(String[] params) {
    for(String s : params) {
       if(hashSet.contains(s)) {
           // do something
           break;
       }
    }
}
```